# python lost data-descriptor as a instance attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, instance, attr, descriptor

```
class data_attr_set_pass(object):
    def __init__(self, inner=None, name=""):
        self.inner = inner
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.inner
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ":" + str(self.inner)

class data_attr(object):
    def __init__(self, inner=None, name=""):
        self.inner = inner
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.inner
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.inner = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ":" + str(self.inner)

class non_data_attr(object):
    def __init__(self, inner=None, name=""):
        self.inner = inner
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.inner
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ":" + str(self.inner)

class Myclass(object):
    x = data_attr_set_pass(11, "class attr")
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = data_attr(890, "instance attr")
print(Myclass.x)
m = Myclass()
print(Myclass.x)
print(m.x)
print(Myclass.__dict__)
print(m.__dict__)
```

output:

```
11
11
11
{'__module__': '__main__', 'x': class attr:11, '__init__': <function Myclass.__init__ at 0x7f0dcc2d1378>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Myclass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Myclass' objects>, '__doc__': None}
{}
```

I had some tests for usage of python data-descriptor. And one test had very strange behaviour. I know that descriptor should be class attr, it's just a test:). 
I put pass in `__set__` of class `data_attr_set_pass`. So as far as I know, `self.x = data_attr(890, "instance attr")` in `__init__` will put `data_attr(890, "instance attr")` into `self.__dict__`. But it can be found nowhere.

why does it happend and where can I find the data-descriptor?

==================================================================

It's really my misunderstanding, I just run first test in code below in which I put 2 into `self.__dict__["x"]` directly, the second one can prove it.

```
class Myclass(object):
    x = data_attr_set_pass(11, "class attr")
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__["x"] = 2
print(Myclass.x)
m = Myclass()
print(Myclass.x)
print(m.x)
print(Myclass.__dict__)
print(m.__dict__)


print('================')
class Myclass(object):
    x = data_attr_set_pass(1324, "class attr")
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2232
print(Myclass.x)
m = Myclass()
print(Myclass.x)
print(m.x)
print(Myclass.__dict__)
print(m.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say

> I put pass in `__set__` of class `data_attr_set_pass`. So as far as I know, `self.x = data_attr(890, "instance attr")` in `__init__` will put `data_attr(890, "instance attr")` into `self.__dict__`.

But why would it do that? You didn't write `data_attr_set_pass.__set__` to insert the value into the instance `__dict__`. You wrote your `__set__` to do nothing but `pass`.

Assigning something to `self.x` does exactly what you wrote your `__set__` to do: nothing.